# Why is the burning temperature of different species of wood so different?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, physical-chemistry, combustion

If you have read Farenheit 451, you may have the idea that paper (or perhaps wood in general) burns at 451F. However, in fact, different species of wood burn at widely different temperatures. Here is a summary:

```
Wood Type   Wood Burning Temperature [degrees Celsius/Fahrenheit]
Western Red Cedar   354 °C /669.2 °F
Redwood 364 °C /687.2 °F
Radiata pine    349 °C /660.2 °F
Douglas fir 350 °C /662 °F
Oak 900 °C /1652 °F
Victorian ash   311 °C /591.8 °F
Birch   816 °C /1500.8 °F
Spruce  620 °C /1148 °F
Beech   950 °C /1742 °F
```

So, we can see that while Victorian Ash burns at 592F, Beechwood burns at a whopping 1742F, way way hotter.

Why is this?

Comment: A work of *fiction* like *Fahrenheit 451* should not be mistaken for a scientific statement of *fact*. Measuring the 'burning temperature' of wood is not easy but drier woods probably burn hotter. Please provide a reference for your data.

Comment: Do you mean *ignition* temperature?

Answer (score 5):

All wood is made predominantly from cellulose and lignin in a certain proportion, and a pound of these will have the same number of carbon-carbon bonds to be broken no matter what kind of tree that wood was cut from. This means that to first order and probably better than that, there *should* be no difference in the *energy release* between different kinds of wood on a per-pound basis.

However, I guarantee you that the energy release *rate* will depend on how dense that pound of wood is. I can blow a dust collection system and the building containing it to smithereens in an instant if the wood has been ground to fine enough powder and mixed with air before ignition, whereas that same weight of wood would burn for an hour if lit as a solid log instead.

I suspect therefore that this data was not generated in a calorimeter with identical oxygen flow rates, etc. and hence is not particularly useful. Note that you'd need very sophisticated thermometry techniques to obtain *four-place accuracy* which this data table contains- and where are the error bars, while we are at it?

Note also that the usual manner in which data like this is presented is in the form of *heating value* expressed in BTU's per pound.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to be precise about temperatures at which wood burns or ignites. It depends on things other than the species of wood.

For example freshly cut wood is often twice as dense as dried wood. Half the mass is water. Dried wood burns much more easily and hotter than wet wood. For wet wood, much of the heat goes into heating water.

Igniting wet wood is often most easily done by heating a little until it dries out. Then you have dry wood.

You can take that a step farther. Wood contains a lot of relatively volatile compounds. Heating it without oxygen drives them off without burning the less volatile compounds. What is left is charcoal, which is mostly carbon. It burns hotter than wood.

When you burn wood, there are stages to the fire. At first you have a flame. After a while, heat drives off water and volatiles. What you have left is glowing embers essentially made of charcoal.

The amount of oxygen getting to the fire changes its temperature. This is what the damper on a fireplace is for.

It may be that the species of wood matters. Many species of plants have discovered wood independently. There are differences of structure between species. Balsa wood is famously light and ironwood is famously dense. Wood has channels to transport water up the trunk. Cherry has a tight grain with small channels. You can literally blow smoke down the length of a foot of solid oak. There are chemical differences as well as structural. I have heard that an oak fire is hotter than pine, but I don't really know.

Some species of birch make very good tinder. The bark is thin and papery. It lights easily because of its thin shape.

Comment: Burning and igniting are two different things. For example, if you have a nichrome wire and you set that nichrome wire to 600F and hold it against a piece of oak, then eventually that oak will begin to burn. But when it burns the temperature of embers will rise to what it says in my question, 1652F.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what a "burning temperature" is, or what test or tests are used to determine it, but any "burning temperature" or "ignition temperature" would not a property of a material or an object. It would depend on the specific test used to determine it.

Regarding "Fahrenheit 451" (233 C), that happens to be the auto (self) *ignition* temperature of paper based on the specific test in [ASTM D1929 “Standard Test Method for Determining Ignition Temperatures of Plastics”](https://www.astm.org/d1929-20.html), though the test is not restricted to plastics.

The test basically involves a very small sample of material placed in a specially designed oven. The temperature of the air surrounding the specimen is gradually increased until the vapors of the specimen ignite (without the use of a pilot flame or arc). My experience with the test and other types of ignition tests indicate that the ASTM test yields a very conservative (low) value, from a fire safety perspective, of ignition temperature.

But the application of the ignition temperature test, (or "burning" temperature test, whatever that may be), is not to predict material fire behavior in actual applications, but to compare the relative behavior (ignitability or otherwise) of different materials subjected to the same test procedure. The actual temperatures will depend on many factors that vary from circumstance to circumstance.

*Bottom Line: That being said, the temperatures shown for the various wood types cannot be compared to one another unless the same test is used to determine them all. And you certainly can't compare the values to the self (auto) ignition temperature of paper (451 F),  unless the test used was ASTM D1929.*

Hope this helps.

Comment: I very much appreciate the reference to the ASTM standard. Bradbury reportedly got the title by calling his local firehouse and asking the person who answered the phone, which I always thought seemed like a super-dodgy source for a phrase-cum-factoid which has had such a big impact on literature and culture.

Comment: @rob Thanks for the edit, as I was about to do so. But I am also correcting my reference to the  standard number to D1929

Comment: The question does not concern the ignition temperature. It concerns the burning temperature which is different than the ignition temperature.

Comment: @AmbroseSwasey I don't know what you mean by the "burning temperature". What temperature is that? And what test would be used to determine that? And in any case, 451 F refers to an ignition temperature so it should not be compared to the temperatures shown, even if they are ignition temperatures, and certainly shouldn't be compared to some other "burning temperature", whatever that means. But I will concede to you that the temperatures cited are probably not ignition temperatures, since they seem way too high for any ignition test that I'm aware of, so I will revise to point that out. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD If you read the question, the lead in is intended to suggest why the average layperson has the WRONG idea about burning temperature, ie they confuse ignition temperature with burning temperature, as you obviously have. The question is about variation in burning temperature.

Comment: @AmbroseSwasey  Don't you assume I "obviously" don't know the difference between ignition and burning temperature. That and the statement "if you read the question" Icomes across as an insult.  I just don't know what you or the OP mean by "burning temperature". (I've revised my answer to say so). Since you seem to be familiar with the term "burning temperature" perhaps you can educate me by first telling me what reputable standardized test or tests is (are) used to determine it. If no tests exist, the term is meaningless.

Comment: @BobD I really don't see how that is relevant. If you don't know what burning temperature is, then you are not the right person to be answering the question.

Comment: @AmbroseSwasey. You still haven't told me what "burning temperature" means and what test is used to determine it. Until you do, IMO it is your comment that is irrelevant. But I choose not to go to war with you on this, so as far as I'm concerned this discussion has ended.